# How to specify the Configuration file when writing scripts for MacBook Air computer?

Tags: c, macos, config, zshrc

I am learning now how to write scripts on my Apple MacBook Air computer.
I understand that it is related to `.zshrc` file.
I will have to create my own C functions.
I will put functions in a directory ---->>> `MyOwnFuncDir`
My understanding is I have to secify this `MyOwnFuncDir` in     some kind of Configuration file.
But how do I let the system know what is the name of this   Configuration file and where is the file located?

This is the content of the `.zshrc` file, I have created so far:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/Users/grigoryzubkis
echo  "#1"
chmod   755 /Users/grigoryzubkis/RunIt
chmod   755 /Users/grigoryzubkis/simplemenu.sh
chmod   755 /Users/grigoryzubkis/learnUnix.sh
echo "#2"
```

Comment: Do you mean C functions or Z shell functions?

Comment: It is unclear what you mean with "C functions". Compiled C programs that can be run from the shell? A library of C functions that can be used to compile C programs? The line `export PATH=$PATH:/Users/grigoryzubkis` tells the system that the directory `/Users/grigoryzubkis` contains programs or scripts that can be run by typing its name only, e.g. `RunIt`. `.zshrc` is sourced in every *interactive* shell. If you want to use the commands in `zsh` scripts, it should better be in `.zshenv`. The `chmod` commands don't belong into `.zshrc` because these are needed only once, not in every shell.

Comment: Q1. It is unclear what you mean with "C functions".  
A1. I mean , that I want to code my own function written in C language. E.g. a function that will have 3 arguments :  
     my first name,   
     my last name,  
     my address  
The function will print on my printer a page with 30 mailing labels.  
Q2. Compiled C programs that can be run from the shell?   
A2. No. At this point of my learning cycle, I do not want to deal with compiling C program.

Comment: Q3. A library of C functions that can be used to compile C programs?  
A3. No. At this point of my learning cycle, I do not want to deal with compiling C program.  
Q4. The line export PATH=$PATH:/Users/grigoryzubkis tells the system that the directory /Users/grigoryzubkis  
    contains programs or scripts that can be run by typing its name only, e.g. RunIt.  
A4. I understand that.

Comment: Q5. .zshrc is sourced in every interactive shell. If you want to use the commands in zsh scripts,   
       it should better be in .zshenv. ?
A5. I think, I understand. I should also create a .zshenv file in the same directory as my .zshrc file. Right?   
Q6. .The chmod commands don't belong into .zshrc because these are needed only once, not in every shell.  
A6. I  do not understand. Where do I put the chmod command for  .zshenv file?